# How do you find the direction of magnetic field given the electric field?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, magnetic-fields, electric-fields, poynting-vector

Say you're asked to find the poynting vector of a wave and you're given an electric field component of the E M traveling wave.

You will need to find B using E=cB, but how would you find the direction of B?

Is there a special RHR for that?

Comment: maybe it would be helpful to take a look at Maxwell's Equations :-)

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/magfor.html  I don't think this answers your question directly, but follow the related links.. also http://www.physicsclassroom.com is pretty good, I am not sure if their site is complete yet

Comment: I assume you're speaking about the magnetic field caused by the electric field (or visa versa). If you're speaking of an electromagnetic wave traveling in a given direction the answers easy. Look up the right hand rule in this context. If you're speaking of a moving charge, same thing.

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is the electric field of the wave, there is no way to uniquely determine the magnetic field direction.  You do know that $\vec{k}$, $\vec{B}$, and $\vec{E}$ are all at right angle to each other;  but without more information, all you know is that $\vec{B}$ lies in the plane perpendicular to $\vec{E}$.  On the other hand, if you know the direction of propagation, then you can find $\vec{B}$ by using the fact that $\omega \vec{B} = \vec{k} \times \vec{E}$ for a plane wave in vacuum.

Of course, if you know the direction of propagation, then it's probably easier to find the Poynting vector by noting that it's always parallel to the direction of propagation (in vacuum);  you don't necessarily need to calculate $\vec{B}$ (magnitude or direction) at all.